# Attempting to run ansible in a Lambda function - unable to get the dependencies to an acceptable size for upload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ansible

I'm following the instructions from the following link:
https://medium.com/@jacoelho/ansible-in-aws-lambda-980bb8b5791b

I've installed ansible in a separate directory, but the total space is 382M. Lambda only allows 250MB after unzipping.

```
drwxrwxr-x 20 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K Mar 29 23:55 ansible
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  157 Mar 29 23:57 ansible-3.1.0-py3.7.egg-info
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  157 Mar 29 23:55 ansible_base-2.10.7-py3.7.egg-info
drwxrwxr-x 42 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K Mar 29 23:56 ansible_collections
drwxrwxr-x  6 ec2-user ec2-user   88 Mar 29 23:55 ansible_test
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  243 Mar 29 23:55 bin
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K Mar 29 23:55 cffi
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  126 Mar 29 23:55 cffi-1.14.5.dist-info
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ec2-user ec2-user 837K Mar 29 23:55 _cffi_backend.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user   38 Mar 29 23:55 cffi.libs
drwxrwxr-x  5 ec2-user ec2-user  160 Mar 29 23:55 cryptography
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  162 Mar 29 23:55 cryptography-3.4.7.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K Mar 29 23:55 jinja2
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  130 Mar 29 23:55 Jinja2-2.11.3.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user  169 Mar 29 23:55 markupsafe
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  106 Mar 29 23:55 MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user  249 Mar 29 23:55 packaging
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  143 Mar 29 23:55 packaging-20.9.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user   38 Mar 29 23:55 __pycache__
drwxrwxr-x  4 ec2-user ec2-user  271 Mar 29 23:55 pycparser
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  102 Mar 29 23:55 pycparser-2.20.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  102 Mar 29 23:55 pyparsing-2.4.7.dist-info
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user 267K Mar 29 23:55 pyparsing.py
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  102 Mar 29 23:55 PyYAML-5.4.1.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K Mar 29 23:55 yaml
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user   44 Mar 29 23:55 _yaml
```

These are all the dependencies. What can I get rid of to make this fit, or is there another way for me to keep them all but still have them be under 250MB? (I heard about a zip in zip method.)

Comment: I'm not sure it makes any sense to run something of this size in Lambda, but you could look at [container image options](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/). Or find some way to optimize (and I use the word loosely) the Ansible dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. I figured out where the bulk of the size was, it was ansible collections that weren't used. Adding an answer to this question soon.

Comment: The article you refer to is quite old, at the time Ansible was lightweight, it then grew up to 3000 modules and became heavier. Since ansible 3.0.0 it's more modular with collections. You should install ansible-base and then add the collections you need.

Comment: There is also always the option to mount an EFS volume with the dependencies on it or to download the pre-packaged dependencies from S3 during init. I wouldn't recommend any of it, but in the end those are also workarounds that weren't mentioned yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use **layers** for all libraries that you need for lambda.
This will help you reuse the libraries.

- upload the lambda
- add layers

[AWS layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)